# Suppose $N \cap K = \{e_G\}$. Prove that for all $a \in N$ and $b \in K, ab = ba.$

Tags: group-theory, normal-subgroups

> Let $G$ be a group and let $N$ and $K$ be normal subgroups of $G.$ Suppose $N \cap K = \{e_G\}$. Prove that for all $a \in N$ and $b \in K, ab = ba.$

I am seeing that all normal subgroups are not necessarily abelian so I am not sure what tools to use for this one.

Comment: Note: Please include the whole question in the body of the post. The title is a way to help readers categorize the question, and not something that is not contained in the post itself. What you are doing is like starting a letter on the envelope, and then continuing mid-sentence at the first line of the first page inside.

Comment: As to the question: Hint: $ab=ba$ if and only if $(ab)(ba)^{-1}=1$, if and only if $aba^{-1}b^{-1}=1$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Yeh well this is annoying because I have received a downvote for doing what you suggested. At this point I don't know how to post these questions. So yeh thanks for the downvote. :)

Comment: “I received a downvote for doing what you suggested”. I suggested that you include the information in the post, not just the title. You certainly did not do so. So what suggestion is it you think you have followed?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Let me clarify: I received a downvote in the past for doing what you suggested. I can see how that was confusing.

Comment: And they told you the downvote was because you repeated information, and only for that?  Frankly, I doubt that was the case; I think it far more likely that you took the wrong lesson from whatever the complaint was. The subject line is not the first line of an e-mail; the instructions on the envelope are not the start of the letter; and the subject line here should not be used the way you are using it. It’s annoying. The subject line should inform readers of the general thrust of your problem, not be a catalog of key hypotheses that are never mentioned again.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin You don't know what happened with the other question so don't assume that you know precisely what went down. ANYWAYS I'll take your advice for what it is. People have been perfectly fine with understanding my questions and how I have been posting them. Thanks. Thats it.

Comment: Well, I just went through all your questions, and the only one without an obvious reason for a downvote has no comments telling you to not put the same information on the title and in the body. Perhaps you can point me to the question you claim this happened with? Then I can take issue with whoever gave you wrong advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By normality, $aba^{-1}\in K$.  And by normality of $N$, $ba^{-1}b^{-1}\in N$.

Now $(aba^{-1})b^{-1}\in K$ and $a(ba^{-1}b^{-1})\in N$.

Thus $aba^{-1}b^{-1}\in N\cap K=\{e\}$.

We can conclude that $ab=ba$.

Comment: This may be an obvious one but to confirm or to fix my way of thinking if I am wrong but is $a(ba^{-1}b^{-1}) \in N$ specifically because its  subgroup and inverses are in there and also because of closure so the product of all those elements will be in there? I guess I got confused with the $ba^{-1}b^{-1}$ because for a normal subgroup I thought it had to specifically look like $bab^{-1}$

Comment: N is normal. That means it's closed under conjugation. Note that $a^{-1}$ is in $N.$  So,  $ba^{-1}b^{-1}$ has to be in $N.$ Finally, both $a $ and $ba^{-1}b^{-1}$ are in $N,$ and hence their product is in $N$ due to closure property of $N.$

Comment: ok yes makes sense :)

Comment: @PhysicsBish please don't unaccept an answer that you've already accepted. This seems rude. Thanks.

Comment: @James I didn't do that. I came back on this page and it was unaccepted. So I thought maybe someone did that, I don't get this website sometimes so I just went with it and chose the other answer that I also liked. So yeh, sorry if it seemed that way but I did not do that. Im pretty confused about how that happened.

Comment: @James I switched it back. I really thought someone changed it because they thought it wasn't acceptable. Yeh I don't know. Anyways I agree that would seem totally rude I would never do that

Comment: Thanks so much for your clarification. I appreciate that. In that case, I don't know it happens.

Comment: Good job! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Note that $ab(ba)^{-1}$ is in both $N$ and $K$ by definition. Hence, $ab(ba)^{-1}$ must be equal to $1_G.$ This proves the result. Lemme know if you have any question.

A little more elaboration:

$ab(ba)^{-1}= (aba^{-1})b^{-1}.$  Note that $aba^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ both are in $K.$ Therefore, their product has to be in $K.$ Similar argument shows that $ab(ba)^{-1}$ is in $N.$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to help.

Comment: So when you say $ab(ba)^{-1}$ is in $N$ and $K$ by definition, is that from the closure property of the group?

Comment: Perfect. You're absolutely correct.

Comment: I see I see. Thanks :)